# Enabling SSL causes multiple redirects

Tags: redirection, ssl

I enabled SSL over all my pages in order to increase security, and I kept receiving "Access Denied" Pages.

However, using google PageSpeed Tests, the page now has two redirects:

```
http://arpbookstore.com/cemevents
http://arpbookstore.com/cemevents/
https://arpbookstore.com/cemevents/
```

How do I avoid having multiple redirects using drupal when enabling SSL via .htaccess redirect?